# Retrieve name of leaf(box) of amchart4 treeMap

Tags: amcharts, treemap

I followed the question here [Retrieving object from TreeMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55969915/retrieving-object-from-treemap) but I am unable to get the name out of it like for in

```
chart.data = [{
  "name": "First",
  "value": 190
}, {
  "name": "Second",
  "value": 289
}, {
  "name": "Third",
  "value": 635
}, {
  "name": "Fourth",
  "value": 732
}, {
  "name": "Fifth",
  "value": 835
}]
```

I want to get name like First, Second and so on. on hit event how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so it was bit deeper than I thought:

```
var series = chart.seriesTemplates.create("0");
series.columns.template.events.on('hit', function(ev) {
  console.log(ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.dataContext.name);
});
```

instead of

```
console.log(ev.target.dataItem)
```